# Add vertices at the intersection of edges

Tags: vertices, geometry

This question was asked many times before, but the most suggested solution "Use Auto Merge" didn't seem to do the trick for me.

I have a grid of overlapping edges as in the attached picture and want to create a vertex at each intersection. The edges do not have any vertices at the intersection point yet. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). There's a useful TinyCAD addon inside Blender which can do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A would fill the hole with polygons and then deleted the faces to have a a result you want. Sadly I dont know if there is a possibility to create a vertex in intersection of two edges.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks, this is a solution indeed. It's a pity I can only use it for one vertex at a time and not select the entire grid and then use it, but I'll get there eventually.

Comment: @JachymMichal Nevermind, turns out I was just not using the right command. Using "XALL | Intersect selected edges" Did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Re *"This question was asked many times before"*: Can you link to some of those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed, select all the edges and  use the shipped add-on *TinyCAD > XALL* to put a vertex at the intersections of all the lines simultaneously. All those intersections have to be detected. This can get (Python) computationally expensive in more complex cases..

More Blenderish, here, IMO, would be to delete all those edges, start from a clean perimeter, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>  *Face Menu > Grid Fill* the empty rectangle, (*constructing* the intersections instead; much cheaper,) before <kbd>X</kbd> deleting 'Only Faces', if you want the bare edges.